# Transaction ordering when one transaction redeems another within a block

Tags: transactions, protocol, block

Say we have txA and txB, and txB contains an input that redeems an output from txA.

In order for a block containing both txA and txB to be valid, is it necessary that txB be after txA in the list of transactions for that block?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35719/is-there-a-fixed-order-for-all-transactions-in-the-block-chain/35726#35726

Comment: While I agree that the question is the same, the answer to the other question is simply a long-winded "yes", without any references or sources. How can I mark an answer as correct if I can't judge whether it's correct or not?